# keep getting syntax error in python

Tags: python, syntax

I'm doing the MIT open courseware class 6.00 Introduction to Computer Science and Programming and I'm stucked in the problem 2 of the 8th assignment where I'm supposed to create a greedy algorithm to give students the best subjects possible depending on a value, work relationship.

this is the part of my code where i get a syntax error and can't seem to figure out what's wrong:

```
subjects={'6.00':   (16,   8),'1.00':   (7,    7),'6.01':   (5,    3), '15.01':  (9,    6)}


def greedyAdvisor(subjects, maxWork, comparator):
    """
    Returns a dictionary mapping subject name to (value, work) which includes
    subjects selected by the algorithm, such that the total work of subjects in
    the dictionary is not greater than maxWork.  The subjects are chosen using
    a greedy algorithm.  The subjects dictionary should not be mutated.

    subjects: dictionary mapping subject name to (value, work)
    maxWork: int >= 0
    comparator: function taking two tuples and returning a bool
    returns: dictionary mapping subject name to (value, work)
    """

    bestSubjects={}
    currentWork=0
    NA=['0']
    while currentWork<maxWork:
        candidate=find_best_sub(subjects,comparator)
        candidate_work= find_work(candidate)
        if candidate_work+currentWork<=15:
          d2={candidate:subjects[candidate]
          NA.append(candidate)
          bestSubjects.update(d2)
          currentWork+=candidate_work
        elif candidate_work+currentWork>15:
              continue
      return bestSubjects




def find_best_sub(subjects,comparator, NA):
    """returns the best subject according to a comparator, the subject must be available so if it's in the NA list it wont be considered"""
  subs= subjects.keys()
  subs=list(subs)
  best_subject='1.00'
  for subject in subs:
    if subject not in NA:
        if comparator(subjects[subject],subjects[best_subject])== True:
          best_subject= subject
        elif comparator(subjects[subject],subjects[best_subject])== False:
          continue
  return best_subject

def find_work(subjects,sub):
  work=sub[WORK]
  return work
```

Comment: "this is the part of my code where i get a syntax error" - that looks a lot like *all* your code. What did you try to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Also, just saying "I get a syntax error" makes your code very hard to debug. Paste the actual error, with traceback. Even if that looks like gobbledegook to you, it's incredibly useful to the people trying to help you.

Comment: @afkfurion: Don't edit the syntax error out of a question about a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can often happen, the erroring line is one above the one being reported:

```
      d2={candidate:subjects[candidate]
      NA.append(candidate)
```

In this case you aren't closing the brace in `d2` declaration

```
      d2={candidate:subjects[candidate]} #<--- here
      NA.append(candidate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
          d2={candidate:subjects[candidate]
          NA.append(candidate)
```

You dropped a brace.

Next time, look at the error message:

```
    NA.append(candidate)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

then look at the line it's pointing to and the line above it.